# Distinguish if the sentence is positive or negative

Tags: python, if-statement

```
neg=['no','not',"don't",'have no interest in']
verb=['like','love','want']
senten=['I love apples.', 'I do not like grapes', 'I have no interest in wanting bananas.','No love for cars']
```

I would like to know if my senten is positive or negative. If the string in senten contains only the verb, then print "1". but if neg comes before verb, I will give it a "-1".

Example:

```
like +1
love +1
want +1
no like -1
not want -1
don't love -1
```

Code:

```
for j in senten:
    j=j.lower()
    if any(x in j for x in verb):
        first_match = list(filter(lambda x: x in j, verb))[0]
        loca=j.find(first_match)  #location of the first word
        #the sentence might be too short.
        if int(loca)<=3:
            if j[int(loca)-3:int(loca)-1]== "no": 
                print(j)
                print(-1)
                continue
        elif int(loca)<=4:
            if j[int(loca)-3:int(loca)-1]== "no" or j[int(loca)-4:int(loca)-1]== "not":
                print(j)
                print(-1)
                continue
        elif int(loca)<=6:
            if j[int(loca)-3:int(loca)-1]== "no" or j[int(loca)-4:int(loca)-1]== "not" or j[int(loca)-6:int(loca)-1]== "don't":
                print(j)
                print(-1)
                continue
        elif int(loca)<=22:
            if j[int(loca)-3:int(loca)-1]== "no" or j[int(loca)-4:int(loca)-1]== "not" or j[int(loca)-6:int(loca)-1]== "don't" or j[int(loca)-20:int(loca)-1]== "have no interest in":
                print(j)
                print(-1) 
                continue                
        print(j)
        print(1)
```

My code has no error and it prints:

```
i love apples.
1
i do not like grapes
-1
i have no interest in wanting bananas.
-1
no love for cars
-1
```

But I would like to ask for an advice if there's a better way to write it? Cause I will add more words in neg, I need to do lots of if or statement and it might not be efficient. Thanks :)

Comment: Scan the sentence through both arrays and add or minus the score of the sentence as a whole. So if the maths makes it < 0 then it would be negative? Or am i misunderstanding what you want here?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for any negative, followed by a space, followed by any verb.

```
for s in senten:
    for v in verb:
        for n in neg:
            if n + ' ' + v in s:
                print('found a negative')
```

Answer (score 0):

you could simplify the could as follow:

```
neg=['no','not',"don't",'have no interest in']
verb=['like','love','want']
senten=['I love apples.', 'I do not like grapes', 'I have no interest in wanting bananas.','No love for cars', "There's no sun, but I still love the weather."]

for chk in senten:
    cnt=0
    for n in neg:
        for v in verb:
            if n+' '+ v in chk.lower():
                cnt+=1
    if cnt > 0:
        print("(-)", chk)
    else:
        print("(+)", chk)
```

---

results will look like:

- (+) I love apples.
- (-) I do not like grapes
- (-) I have no interest in wanting bananas.
- (-) No love for cars
- (+) There's no sun, but I still love the weather.

Comment: There's one problem, if a string is "There's no sun, but I still love the weather.", with your code is (-), but it should be a positive. That's why I stated to check if the neg comes before the verb :)

Comment: I have updated the code to reflect your comment. I have used the same concept with of @john-gordon